# Converting Complex PHP Rotate Functions to Work in 64-bit

Tags: php, algorithm, bit-manipulation, 32bit-64bit

A number of years back, my webhost changed from 32-bit to 64-bit, and a critical PHP script stopped working. It was a due to the << and >> (bit shift) operations having changed. I was able to fix my problem by replacing the rotateleft and rotateright routines with rotateleft32 and rotateright32 like this:

```
function rotateleft($value, $numleft) {
  return (($value << $numleft) | ($value >> (32-$numleft)));
}
function rotateleft32($value, $numleft) {
  return ((($value << $numleft) | ($value >> (32-$numleft))) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}

function rotateright($value, $numright) {
  return (($value >> $numright) | ($value << (32-$numright)));
}
function rotateright32($value, $numright) {
  return ((($value >> $numright) | ($value << (32-$numright))) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

I have now come across a new set of code that seems to be exactly the same issue, but it is more complicated:

```
function ECC_RotateLeft($a)
{
    $copya = makecopy($a);
    $bit = ($copya->e[0] & ECC_UPRBIT) ? 1 : 0;

    /* looped
    for ($i = 0; $i < ECC_MAXLONG - 1; $i++)
    $copya->e[$i] = ($copya->e[$i] << 1) | (($copya->e[$i + 1] & ECC_MSB) ? 1 : 0);
    $copya->e[0] &= ECC_UPRMASK;
    looped */

    /* unlooped */
    // These lines are optimized for ECC_MAXLONG==4 only!
    $bit = ($copya->e[0] & ECC_UPRBIT) ? 1 : 0;
    $copya->e[0] = (($copya->e[0] << 1) & ECC_UPRMASK) | (($copya->e[1] & ECC_MSB) ? 1 : 0);
    $copya->e[1] = ($copya->e[1] << 1) | (($copya->e[2] & ECC_MSB) ? 1 : 0);
    $copya->e[2] = ($copya->e[2] << 1) | (($copya->e[3] & ECC_MSB) ? 1 : 0);
    /* unlooped */

    $copya->e[3] = ($copya->e[3] << 1) | $bit;
    return $copya;
}

function ECC_RotateRight($a)
{
    $copya = makecopy($a);
    $bit = ($copya->e[ECC_NUMWORD] & 1) ? ECC_UPRBIT : 0;

    /* looped
    for ($i = ECC_MAXLONG - 1; $i > 0; $i--)
    $copya->e[$i] = (($copya->e[$i] >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) | (($copya->e[$i - 1] & 1) ? ECC_MSB : 0);
    looped */

    /* unlooped */
    // Thes lines are optimized for ECC_MAXLONG==4 only!
    $copya->e[3] = (($copya->e[3] >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) | (($copya->e[2] & 1) ? ECC_MSB : 0);
    $copya->e[2] = (($copya->e[2] >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) | (($copya->e[1] & 1) ? ECC_MSB : 0);
    $copya->e[1] = (($copya->e[1] >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) | (($copya->e[0] & 1) ? ECC_MSB : 0);
    /* unlooped */

    $copya->e[0] = (($copya->e[0] >> 1) & 0x7FFFFFFF) | $bit;
    return $copya;
}
```

I have three problems in trying to fix this myself:

1. It is not my code, so I am not familiar with what it's trying to do.
2. I no longer have a 32-bit server to test it against
3. I am adequate, but not an expert in PHP.

I'd like to know if anyone does see a simple fix to allow this code to work on a 64-bit server and give the same result as it would have on a 32-bit server.

If not, how would you recommend I debug this given that I don't have a 32-bit result to compare against?

---

Here is some discussion regarding this problem, and an attempt to get the developer to fix it:
[How to get the outdated 32bit keymaker.php Script Working on 64 bit](http://forum.siliconrealms.com/index.php?s=&showtopic=5626)

Comment: You should set up a 32-bit version of PHP, perhaps by first running a 32-bit VM.

Comment: Also, if you aren't able to do a head-to-head comparison, how do you know that it's the above code that's the issue?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It's an educated guess, based on the fix I needed originally and on the related Stackoverflow question I had then asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397738/32-to-64-bit-gotchas-in-php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answering all *four* of your questions:

1. `It is not my code, so I am not familiar with what it is trying to do.`

While I could go into tracing and debugging procedures in detail, I will instead recommend the classics. I *highly* recommend [picking this up](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672) if this is your day job or you have more than a passing interest in refactoring code in the future.

2. `I no longer have a 32-bit server to test it against`

As mentioned by Oli in the errata, you'll want to set up a [32-bit VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) or [chroot](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24575), dependent upon the OS your server is running.

3. `I am adequate, but not an expert in PHP.`

As above, if this is more than just a spot issue, I recommend [the](http://php.net/docs.php) [classics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565926103.do).

4. *(Fixing the actual code)*

First off, eww. No documentation, comment cruft, duplicate logic, and unexpressive variable names that fail to encapsulate their logic effectively. It's not the worst code I've seen, but I empathize with you here.

Still, the result isn't necessarily *wrong*. If you don't have a series of unit tests for it in your code base, [I recommend adding them](http://www.simpletest.org/).

If you wish to benchmark the efficiency of this function, I highly recommend comparing it to the results of [the algorithms defined in the notes here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). Ideally, you'll want one of the implementations [closest to this reference implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift).

Stealing one off the top of that thread and repurposing it to your API:

```
function ECC_RotateLeft($value,$amount) {
    if ($amount>0) {
        $amount %= 32;
        $value = ($value<<$amount) | ($value>>(32-$amount));
    }
    return $value;
}

function ECC_RotateRight($value,$amount) {
    if ($amount>0) {
        $amount %= 32;
        $value = ($value>>$amount) | ($value<<(32-$amount));
    }
    return $value;
}
```

(No surprise that this looks similar to the implementation you initially provided.)

Why am I including `$amount` as part of the specification? Simple: it doesn't violate [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) like the code you're refactoring. It looks like this can be set to `($copya->e[0] & ECC_UPRBIT) ? 1 : 0` as needed.

In short: the easiest way to refactor code isn't necessarily to look at its contained logic. Sometimes, determining intent and finding a good reference implementation is all that's needed.

Comment: +1 Great and educative answer, are you a teacher by any chance?

Comment: @andreas Alas, only the spawn of two of them. I am only a humble cancer researcher at the time of this writing. :)